# Codeigniter HMVC load view of loaded module

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I am using the Codeigniter HMVC from https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc and I want to load a module using the Modules::run('site1') using the view of the said module.

Example:

```
- modules
   - site1
      - controllers
      - views
   - site2
      - controllers
      - views
```

On  site1, I loadded the site2 module using Modules::run('site2/login'); the problem is that it is loading the views of site1 instead of site2 giving me an error of ".. site1/login does not exists".

It should be loading the views of the site2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I was using the $this->load->view($this->router->class . '/login'); and the router class is already my site1 instead of the site2. Is there an easy way for me not to change all the $this->router->class to 'site2'?

Since the part controller is now site1 and site2 is just being loaded as a module, it overrides the $this->router->class from site2 to site1. Is there a way for me to still get the class name of the site2?